# Kerberos Exception launching Spark locally

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, kerberos

I am trying to set up a Spark Testng unit test:

```
@Test
def testStuff(): Unit = {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local"))
    ...
}
```

The code fails with: `IllegalArgumentException: Can't get Kerberos realm`

What am I missing?

Comment: Enabling the Kerberos debug trace could help you understand what happens inside the Hadoop and/or Java Kerberos libraries => `export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true` and `-Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true` cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html plus `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser‌​,logincontext` cf. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html

Comment: On second thoughts, with `spark-submit`, the Java system properties would have to be set inside `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` property... not sure about the proper way to set them when creating directly SparkSession / SparkContext from your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that your JVM is unable to locate the kerberos config (`krb5.conf` file).

Depending on your company's environment/infrastruture you have a few options:

1. Check if your company has standard library to set kerberos authentication.
2. Alternatively try:

   - set JVM property: `-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/file-path/for/krb5.conf`
   - Put the `krb5.conf` file into the `<jdk-home>/jre/lib/security` folder

Comment: I tried #2.a with no success. Where should I set JVM properties to run the test successfully?

Comment: Assuming you are running test inside an IDE then you can pass this as part of runtime arguments.